# htaccess rewrite url folder/file to folder/file.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want `ajax/file` address to be redirected to `ajax/file.php` using .htaccess. I created a .htaccess file like below but that gives a 500 Internal Server Error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ajax/(.*)$ ajax/$1.php [L]
```

An additional information is that my website is working under a sub-folder. (localhost/myproject) `RewriteRule ^ajax/(.*)$ /ajax/$1.php [L]` redirects url to (localhost/ajax/file.php) instead of (localhost/myproject/ajax/file.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that `.*` in your regex also matches `file.php`.

Use your rule like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ajax/([^./]+)/?$ ajax/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: and `[^./]+` supposed to be select file only in file.php. Thank you it works very well!